# Why makecontext/swapcontext does not work with pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock

Tags: c, linux, memory, gcc, stack

I have used **makecontext/swapcontext** successfully for shifting the stack. However, when I try to use it with **pthread_mutex_lock** or **pthread_mutex_unlock**, I always receive segmentation fault. Any idea, why is that so. The code is shown below.

### EDIT

Now I read from the swapcontext manual,

*Due to limitations in the current pthread implementation, makecontext should not be used in programs which link against the pthread(3) library (whether threads are used or not).*

Any workaround to solve this?

```
static const unsigned int SWAP_STACK_SIZE = 8192;
// These are globally defined variables. 
// Since each thread will have its own stack, they are defined as arrays.
static ucontext_t uctx_main[8], uctx_func[8];
static char func_stack[8][SWAP_STACK_SIZE];

// tid is thread ID here, values are 0, 1, 2, 3, etc...
if (getcontext(&uctx_func[tid]) == -1)
    handle_error("getcontext");
uctx_func[tid].uc_stack.ss_sp = func_stack[tid];
uctx_func[tid].uc_stack.ss_size = SWAP_STACK_SIZE;
uctx_func[tid].uc_link = &uctx_main[tid];
makecontext(&uctx_func[tid], (void(*)())pthread_mutex_unlock, 1, &mutex);

if (swapcontext(&uctx_main[tid], &uctx_func[tid]) == -1)
    handle_error("swapcontext");
```

Comment: Probably not a solution for you, but you could use Solaris. I have successfully used context functions and pthreads in a 64-bit program two years ago (Solaris 10, x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual page states that `makecontext` passes the arguments as type `int`. If you are on a 64-bit Linux then pointers will be 64 bits while `int` will be 32 bit, and weird stuff will start to happen.

Comment: OK, if that is the case, can't I make a wrapper function for pthread_mutex_lock, and pass two integers (which when combined represent the address of the mutex) and later pack them in a long variable, so as to pass the address of mutex to the pthread_mutex_lock function from within the wrapper function? What do you think?

Comment: @MetallicPriest It might work, but it's kind of convoluted. :)